# Image not appearing on certain mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a image that is being spun using animation. The image works perfectly on desktop and some mobile devices. However, on certain devices the image does not show. I made sure the HTML validated and the CSS was working properly. Could there be any other reason for this?

```css
#test {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="TESTING" id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Cache issue perhaps?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: can you be more specific? how would i be able to fix it?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without being able to test, but it looks like you are only covering the -webkit prefix for the animation properties.  This might be the issue with some browsers.

Comment: First things first... is your image showing up when your remove all animations (and even all CSS)? Can you share the image? Do you know which devices show or don’t show the image?